# Android -> Get current network type on Android 10 and below

Tags: android, network-programming

How can I get current network type? I found tis solution:

```
val info = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
if (info == null || !info.isConnected()) return "-" // not connected
if (info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) return "WIFI"
if (info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
    val networkType: Int = info.getSubtype()
    return when (networkType) {
                    TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS,
                    TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE,
                    TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA,
                    TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT,
                    TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN,
                    TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GSM -> "2G"
                    TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS,
                    TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0,
                    TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A,
                    TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA,
                    TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA,
                    TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA,
                    TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B,
                    TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD,
                    TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP,
                    TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_TD_SCDMA -> "3G"
                    TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE,
                    TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IWLAN, 19 -> "4G"
                    TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_NR -> "5G"
                    else -> "?"
    }
}
return "?"
```

But it all marked as deprecated. Screenshot:
[image]

Please help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`NetworkInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo) class was deprecated in API 29. So you need to replace the deprecated methods with those mentioned in their notes.

You can use this method for newer API levels:

```
fun getNetwork(): String {
    val connectivityManager =
        context.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    val nw = connectivityManager.activeNetwork ?: return "-"
    val actNw = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(nw) ?: return "-"
    when {
        actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> return "WIFI"
        actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> return "ETHERNET"
        actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> {
            val tm = context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
            when (tm.dataNetworkType) {
                TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS,
                TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE,
                TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA,
                TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT,
                TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN,
                TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GSM -> return "2G"
                TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS,
                TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0,
                TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A,
                TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA,
                TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA,
                TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA,
                TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B,
                TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD,
                TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP,
                TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_TD_SCDMA -> return "3G"
                TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE,
                TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IWLAN, 19 -> return "4G"
                TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_NR -> return "5G"
                else -> return "?"
            }
        }
        else -> return "?"
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding to the answer given by Saurabh, it requires the permission READ_PHONE_STATE